# What is equivalent of GAE appcfg.py request_logs in the new gcloud system

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am in the process of transition my system to use gcloud from the deprecated appcfg.py. Perhaps I did not look properly, but could not transition steps from appcfg to gcloud.

I am specifically interested in downloading the app logs in the Common Log Format (CLF) so that it can be parsed by the awstats log analyzer.

What is the gcloud command that would download logs with CLF format. I have already tried `gcloud app logs read` but it does not return the CLF format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been checking at this command, and it looks like, at this moment, it is not possible to have the logs on CLF.

To have this possibility, I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/111734632). Bear in mind that there is no ETA for it. You can keep an eye on it to see any updates on the matter.

Comment: It is a shame really that massive/prominent gae has gone thru major/strategic upgrades (appcfg to gcloud in this case) that result in important features getting missed out. Without regard to implement quickly or at the minimum provide workarounds..